# [].slice or Array.prototype.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, syntax, prototype

I’v come across both ways to apply Array prototypes to a native object:

```
arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
arr = [].slice.call(obj);
```

In similar fashion, getting the true type of a native array-like object:

```
type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
type = {}.toString.call(obj);
```

A simple test:

```
function fn() {
    console.log(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        [].slice.call(arguments),
        Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments), 
        {}.toString.call(arguments)
    );
}

fn(0,1);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhdmN/

They seem identical to me; the first syntax is used more often, but the second is definitely shorter. Are there any shortcomings when using the shorter syntax?

Comment: the second syntax creates a new object needlessly.

Comment: @DanD., you should post this as an answer, because it is the correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are identical regarding functionality.

However, the `Array` object can be overwritten, causing the first method to fail.

```
//Example:
Array = {};
console.log(typeof Array.prototype.slice); // "undefined"
console.log(typeof [].slice);    // "function"
```

The literal method creates a new instance of `Array` (opposed to `Array.prototype.` method). Benchmark of both methods: http://jsperf.com/bbarr-new-array-vs-literal/3

When you're going to use the method many times, the best practice is to cache the method:

- `var slice = Array.prototype.slice; //Commonly used`
- `var slice = [].slice;` - If you're concerned about the existence of `Array`, or if you just like the shorter syntax.

Comment: No, only the result is identical. Creating new objects for nothing is not the same, and the explicit use of the prototype is also faster because it requires less work for the runtime to figure out where the method resides. Both marginal, but why not go for the better solution if they are equally simple to use?

Comment: @Lucero They're identical for functionaility. The `[].slice` does initialize a new instance (which hardly affect performance). The `Array` method is cleaner, but fails when `Array` is redefined,

Comment: in JS one can break a lot of things. If `Array.prototype.slice` is changed then both variants will not behave as expected. Reminds me of the redefined `undefined`... anyways, creating objects for nothing is not expensive, but factoring in the cost of garbage collection it may add up in a tight loop.

Comment: @Lucero The best of both worlds: caching the variable, using `[].slice` :)

Comment: The jsperf link is not really saying much, except that Firefox 9 is very slow in creating new instances. It would be interesting to see the performance comparison of the both variants seen here.

Comment: I have revised the JSPerf: http://jsperf.com/bbarr-new-array-vs-literal/3. Still a marginal difference. EDIT: Chrome 17 is actually **slower** on `Array.prototype.slice.call`

Comment: You may even use `Object.getPrototypeOf([]).slice` if you have some irrational fear of someone overwriting `Array`. Wait, what if someone overwrites `Object`? ... ;)

Comment: @RobW, `[]` is an instance of  `Array`. If `Array.prototype` doesn't have a `slice()` method then neither do `[]`. Putting performance issues aside then I guess it is a notational convenience as it is very common among JavaScript developers community.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question! Let's pull up the pros (✔️) and cons (❌) for each alternative:

### `[].slice`

- ✔️: Is typed faster
  Two keystrokes, no *shift*-modifier or anything,
  and your linter knows `[.slice` is a typo.
- ✔️: Is read faster
  You can identify the relevant part (`slice`) faster.
- ✔️: Is more popular
  [56M+ snippets on GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%5B%5D.forEach.call) (as of late 2018).
- ✔️: Can't be overwritten
  The first part of [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006580/2427596) demonstrates this perfectly.
- ✔️: Runs faster.
  Wait, what? Well, that's actually the whole point of this answer.

Contrary to what you'd think and read pretty much everywhere, **`[].slice.call(...)` does *NOT* instantiate a new, empty `Array` just to access its `slice` property!**.

Nowadays (it has been so *for 5+ years* – as of late 2018), the **JIT compilation** (1) is included everywhere you run JavaScript (unless you're still browsing the Web with IE8 or lower).

This mechanism allows the JS Engine to: (2)

> ... resolve `[].slice` directly, and **statically**, as direct `Array.prototype` reference in one shot, and just one configurable property access: `forEach`

### `Array.prototype.slice`

- ❌: Is typed slower
  Typos (e.g.: `Array.prorotype.slice`) look fine until you try and run the code.
- ❌: Is less popular
  [8M+ snippets on GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Array.prototype.forEach.call) (as of late 2018).
- ❌: Runs slower
  `Array.prototype.slice` is: (2)

> ... a lookup for **the whole scope** for an `Array` reference until all scopes are walked 'till the **global** one ... because you can name a variable `Array` any time you want.
>
> Once the global scope is reached, and the native found, the engine accesses its proottype and after that its method
> ...
> O(N) scope resolution + 2 properties access (`.prototype` and `.forEach`).

- ✔️: Allows you to seamlessly adapt to whichever coding conventions would strictly prevent you from having a line start with either `(`, `[` or `` ` ``
  Definitely a good thing (sarcastically).
- ✔️: You won't have to explain why `[].slice` is better in pretty much every way.
  Although now, that would just boil down to [clicking the share link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820058/2427596) below

---

#### Disclaimer

Note that, realistically, neither does effectively run *faster* than the other. This isn't the bottleneck of your application.

---

1. You may want to read [A crash course in just-in-time (JIT) compilers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/a-crash-course-in-just-in-time-jit-compilers/)
2. Quoted from *Andrea Giammarchi* ([@WebReflection](https://twitter.com/WebReflection) on Twitter)

Comment: BTW, this is all outdated anyway. The proper, modern (and intuitively understandable) ES6 way for the same is  [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Comment: @rugk Well, I tend to avoid unnecessary use of `Array.from` if possible, for huge array inputs.