# What is the difference between the wording of the first and second written

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [[].slice or Array.prototype.slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006553/slice-or-array-prototype-slice)

the first

```
(function() {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        aArguments = slice.apply(arguments);
})(10, 20, 30);
```

the second

```
(function() {
    var aArguments = [].slice.apply(arguments);
})(10, 20, 30);
```

what's the difference?

only ​​Speed？

Comment: "only Speed?" does this even have a speed difference?

Comment: @Thilo it does. `Array.prototype.slice` is faster then `[].slice`

Comment: @Raynos—probably because the second requires creating a new (useless) array instance every time the expression is evaluated. A better comparison would use `slice = [].slice;` but that's not the OP. For a one-off execution, it's not going to matter.

Comment: @RobG even if it didn't create a useless instance it still has to check whether the Array object has an own property named `"slice"` and then get the `[[Prototype]]` of the object and then get the function that is `Array.prototype.slice`

Comment: For a single operation, the comparison is `[].slice` vs `Array.prototype.slice`. Array is on the global object so is 3 lookups to get to `slice`. The big difference is having to create an array for `[].slice` which is one less lookup (presuming the `[[Prototype]]` doesn't need to be searched for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just different means of getting the same `.slice()` method. Methods on `Array.prototype` are available from all `Array` objects.

- The first one requires more object property lookups.
- The second one requires the creation of a new Array

Performance considerations will likely vary between implementations, and are likely minor.

---

Note that you can also do this if you want all the arguments...

```
var aArguments = Array.apply(null, arguments);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second version, you are creating an Array object.

In the first version, no additional objects are created - you directly reference the function on the Array prototype and work with it.

Comment: You forgot the minification benefit `slice.apply` minifies a lot better then `[].slice.apply`

Comment: @Raynos could you give and example of minification for this example?

Comment: [example](https://gist.github.com/014bb7f79f44d64ff912)

Comment: @Raynos - A temporary variable can be used with either of the [approaches](https://gist.github.com/1878318). I thought you were referring to a minification benefit assuming both of OP's examples used a temporary variable.

Answer (score -1):

The performance difference is negligible.

If you want to see exactly what the performance difference is, take a look at the results of [this performance test](http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-slice-call-vs-slice-call/10), and run it yourself if you like.

Comment: Someone have a problem with this? It's negligible. Look at the graphs. =/