# [].slice.call(this) vs array.prototype.call(this)

Tags: javascript

Just wondering what's the different with the following js script.

```
[].slice.call(this) vs Array.prototype.slice.call(this);
```

They seems to be doing this same, can someone explain the different and which one i should stick with?

Cheers

Comment: It seems you have a typo; `Array`, not `array`, right?

Comment: `Array.prototype.call` is incorrect. Maybe you meant `Array.prototype.slice.call()` ?

Comment: sorry i miss the slice out

Comment: Since it wasn't mentioned explicitly: `Array.prototype.slice === [].slice`. It's the same function, just two different ways to get a reference to it.

Comment: All the answers on this page are outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820058/2427596

Comment: BTW, the modern (and intuitively understandable) ES6 method for the same is  [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are almost identical. Let's examine each of them:

```
[].slice.call(data)
```

What it does?

- `[]` - this creates new Array, same to `new Array()`
- `slice` - it retrieves method `slice` from array
- `call(data)` - it calls `slice()` method replacing its current context with `data` variable, i.e. uses `data` as its internal array, not `[]`. This returns our `data` converted into `Array`.

Now, the second one:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(data)
```

This one:

- `Array.prototype.slice` - retrieves method `slice` from `Array.prototype`; in a nutshell - it returns you `slice` method without any context (internal data).
- `call(data)` - as in previous variant, calls this method with `data` as its context.

**Conclusion**

Both `[].slice` and `Array.prototype.slice` return you a `slice` function which you can call on some array, **however** this array is passed not as argument, but as context (using `call` method of function object). In JavaScript, these calls will be absolutely the same:

```
// Calling as a method of 'Hello' string
'Hello'.indexOf('e') // returns 1

// Calling as unbound method
String.prototype.indexOf.call('Hello', 'e') // returns 1
String.prototype.indexOf.apply('Hello', ['e']) // returns 1
```

Those methods are almost the same. First one is more readable, but second one uses a *bit* less memory because it isn't creating a temporary initial `Array`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew this make sense a lot

Comment: @bluebill1049 another interesting addition: if you call `[].slice()`, it will return an empty array `[]`, and if you do `[1,2,3].slice()`, `[1,2,3]` will be returned. And, on the other hand, calling `Array.prototype.slice()` directly (without `.call`) will always return `[]` because it has no internal context, it's smth like "static metod".

Comment: nice example :) second one is better

Comment: The `slice` method always returns a **new array** containing the sliced elements and modifies the called on instance. So its not "static".

Comment: @LJ_1102 you're right. I should say something like 'unbound' rather than 'static'.

Comment: @AndrewDunai I just wanted to stress the fact that `slice` always returns a new array. So calling slice is an array construction as well. Also the memory usage is not really the crux here but the CPU time to construct and garbage collect these arrays can be problematic in high performance applications.

Comment: *"calling `Array.prototype.slice()` directly ... will always return `[]` because it has no internal context"* That's not exactly true. In that case, `this` will refer to `Array.prototype`. And it so happens that `Array.prototype.length` is `0`. That's why you get an empty array.

Comment: This is actually not true, there is more to it than what is described here. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820058/2427596

Answer (score 1):

Definitely stick with the latter one as the first one is an implicit array construction and the same as:

`new Array().slice.call(this)`

Its constructing a new array that needs to be garbage collected afterwards since you dont use it. While both statements "work", the above mentioned does a lot of extra work, first you construct a new instance, then you look up if the instance itself has a `slice` property, as this is false the `prototype` chain is traversed and the `slice` is found on the `Array.prototype` and then `call`ed. Then you call it with your other array as scope, so essentially render the instance you created useless by using your other one.

Thats why `Array.prototype.slice.call(myarr)` is the **proper** way of accessing the `slice` method.

Comment: oops i didn't give -1, please state the reason who voted the down

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `Array` doesn't actually create an object, where as `[]` is an instance of Array.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.slice.call()` seems slightly more performant, though that makes sense because it would be quicker at runtime to "look up" this method. I posit that `[].slice.call()` is the best choice. [Here's the jsperf of reference](http://jsperf.com/array-perf-prototype-vs-literal/2)

Let's be real, in what case would the negligible difference between the two be a major contributor to poor website performance? sounds like heaven, actually. The shorter syntax of the literal method is awesome. I'd rather save myself the half-second it'd take to type the prototype variant than be shakily more efficient.

**The coffin nail of Array.prototype...** some people say is that it's irresponsible because you risk altering it. But... that's stupid. Figure 1: *`Array.prototype = function() { console.log('foo') };`* Whoopsie... *That probably happens all of the time.* Seriously, even granting its legitimacy is still intact, it takes me longer to type and is imo hideous compared to its sexier literal sister.

**The real answer to your real question is that the functionality is exactly the same. Use whichever you will still appreciate on your deathbed.**

Comment: thanks, @bluebill1049! I like your alias even though it has numbers, and numbers is hard.

Comment: *"some people say is that it's irresponsible because you risk altering it"* I wonder who those people are. I think in this case it's quite difficult to "accidentally" assign a property if all you want is *call* it.

Comment: exactly. perfunctory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006553/slice-or-array-prototype-slice

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf([]).slice.call()` a happy compromise?