# [].slice vs Array.prototype.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the difference between [].slice vs Array.prototype.slice?

While searching, I found Array.prototype.slice to be faster than [].slice at
[jsperf.com/array-prototype-slice-vs-slice](http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-slice-vs-slice).

Why Array.prototype.slice is faster than [].slice?

I have checked [[].slice or Array.prototype.slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006553/slice-or-array-prototype-slice). A more vivid description will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: All the answers on this page are outdated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820058/2427596

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why Array.prototype.slice is faster than [].slice?

`[]` is an instance of `Array`, so the additional overhead is most likely the time it takes to instantiate the object.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed so but got confused by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006553/slice-or-array-prototype-slice#comment-11289799 and then seeing the performance impact at http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-slice-vs-slice +1

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52820058/2427596

Answer (score 4):

`.slice()` is an Array prototype method. It is defined on the Array prototype object, `Array.prototype`, which means that `Array.prototype.slice` is the direct way to reference it.

Array instances, like `[]`, inherit from the Array prototype, so `[].slice` resolves to `Array.prototype.slice`.

If you need to use this method repeatedly, a good approach is to put its reference into a variable in your outermost scope:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
```

and then use this variable via `.call()` and `.apply()` calls, e.g.

```
slice.call( someObj )
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference, I was mainly looking for the reason behind performance impact. +1