# Each() issue in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, each

Everytime I try to reproduce `.each()` jQuery function in vanilla JavaScript, I'm in trouble.

When I try to change this :

```
$("[data-lng]").each(function(){
   var lng = $(this).data('lng');
   $('#language').text(lng)
});
```

To this :

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[data-lng]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elem, function(){
    document.getElementById('language').write = elem.dataset.lng
});
```

Console returns `elem.dataset is not defined`

Plus, I'm dealing with `data` stuff so I'm not even sure if its legal to write this `document.querySelectorAll("[data-lng]")`

Thanks for your help !

**PS :** Here is an example of what I want to convert into vanilla JS :
https://jsfiddle.net/x93oLad8/4/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you use each() at all, in this specific case? Are there multiple buttons/divs? If so, script will not work properly, if not...then....why each()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fairly trivial to swap your jsFiddle example out for vanilla JS. One 'gotcha' to be aware of is that IE has no support for NodeList.prototype.forEach() hence using a regular for loop instead. (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

```js
var dictionary = {
  'greet': {
    'it': 'Ciao',
    'en': 'Hello',
    'fr': 'Salut',
  }
};
var langs = ['it', 'en', 'fr'];
var current_lang_index = 0;
var current_lang = langs[current_lang_index];

window.change_lang = function() {
  current_lang_index = ++current_lang_index % 3;
  current_lang = langs[current_lang_index];
  translate();
}

function translate() {
  /* jQuery:
      $("[data-translate]").each(function(){
      var key = $(this).data('translate');
      $(this).html(dictionary[key][current_lang] || "N/A");
  });*/
  
  /* vanilla */
  var dt = document.querySelectorAll("[data-translate]");
  //iterate over the NodeList:
  for (i = 0; i < dt.length; ++i) {
    var key = dt[i].getAttribute('data-translate');//get the key
    dt[i].innerHTML = (dictionary[key][current_lang] || "N/A");//set the text
  }
  
}

translate();
```

```html
<div data-translate="greet"></div>
<button onclick="change_lang()">Change Language</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, instead of using:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elem, function()
```

You can just use

```
elem.forEach(function()
```

Secondly, callback function can accept arguments (3 of them to be specific):
el - current elem (which is the "this" you are looking for? :))
index - index of current elem in array
list - the nodelist you loop over

Usage:

```
elem.forEach(function(el, index, list){
    console.log(el); //logs current element
});
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

@Edit: Since there was a big discussion in the comments about the first part, i feel obligated to link a thread on overriding default methods in JS: [[].slice or Array.prototype.slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006553/slice-or-array-prototype-slice/9006580#9006580) (a.k.a why elem.forEach might not work, just in case :))

Comment: Also `.querySelectorAll()` does not return an Array instance, and some older browsers don't provide the Array iteration (etc) functions for NodeList objects.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Well someone might override `Array`, or almost any other global.

Comment: Acutally `.querySelectorAll()` does return a NodeList, on which you are free to perform `forEach`. I tested it before i wrote the answer, check link: https://jsfiddle.net/x93oLad8/4/

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Either you guard yourself against all possible global clobbering, or you simply make sure that you don't load any code that clobbers things. The latter is the more reasonable approach in most situations. Claiming odds of one overwrite over another isn't convincing.

Comment: @rockstar I suggest you read a similar answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9006580/859154 regarding override.

Comment: Thanks ! Understood. I'm still searching but I love your debate ^^

Comment: @vicbyte `querySelectorAll` does not return an array.

Comment: @DanielA.White I never stated it does. I just said that you can use forEach on the NodeList type it does return?

Comment: @vicbyte not always. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean by not always?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Well that link illustrates my point. If `Array` is overwritten, then `Array.prototype.forEach` will fail.

Comment: @vicbyte i don't see the need to link something off-topic in the answer. Your answer is completely rigjt i dont know what Royis and Daniels problem is.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Why would anyone override any built-in, except to patch an old/buggy implementation? Why would they do that?

Comment: @Pointy I always assumed that browser legacy support is something that everyone has to account for by himself. Especially that its OP who proposed the `.forEach` :)